# How to put values on a boxplot for median, 1st quartile and last quartile?

Tags: r, boxplot

How to put values on boxplot and control its width?

```
X<-c(1,2,,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7)
```

I need to write values for min, max, 1st quartile, median and last quartile. How can I put it there?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `horizontal = TRUE` get a horizontal boxplot and `axes = FALSE` to remove the axes. `staplewex = 1` sets the staple width the same as the box width

Then you can use `fivenum` to return the statistics used to create the boxplot and use these as text labels, fiddling with the `y` value until you have what you want

```
boxplot(X, horizontal = TRUE, axes = FALSE, staplewex = 1)
text(x=fivenum(X), labels =fivenum(X), y=1.25)
```

[image]

Note that i've inserted a `3` for the value missing in your example data `X`

Comment: Thanks! Can i control the width(in horizontal it's height) of box? I want to make it as narrow as strip.

Comment: Read the help for boxplot. `?boxplot` it is very helpful!

Comment: I already read its documentation and tried width parameter but still could not control its width. Pls help me.

Comment: `boxplot(X, horizontal = TRUE, axes = FALSE, staplewex = 1)`  - it is now in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got, using boxwex can be controlled.

Answer (score 17):

The answer provided by mnel is perfect, assuming —as in the example— that there are not outliers. In that case, the lower and upper whiskers are then equal to the minimum and maximum. But, if there are outliers and we don't specify *`range = 0`* in the boxplot function, we don't get the right values for the labels. Instead, we could use:

```
text(x=boxplot.stats(X)$stats, labels = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, y = 1.25)
```

Let's see an example:

**Horizontally**

```
X <- c(1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,10,15)
boxplot(X, horizontal = TRUE, axes = FALSE, staplewex = 1)
```

1. Incorrect values`text(x = fivenum(X), labels = fivenum(X), y = 1.25)`

[image]

2. Correct values: `text(x = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, labels = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, y = 1.25)`

[image]

**Vertically**

Switching the arguments for x and y inside `text`.

```
boxplot(X, axes = FALSE, staplewex = 1)
text(y = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, labels = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, x = 1.25)
```

[image]

Comment: Can I get same values when plotted vertically ?

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems trying to understand the boxplot quartiles labels and compare to summary function values, so i´d like to share with you.

Sometimes there will be differences in quartiles labels in boxplot using fivenum or stats comparing to r summary function values. This occurs only on even datasets.

e.g.(using text(x = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, labels = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, y = 1.25)):

```
product<-c(3,12,20,25,30,35,70,70,80,150)

summary(product)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
3.00   21.25   32.50   49.50   70.00  150.00 

boxplot(product,horizontal=TRUE,col="grey",staplewex=1,axes=FALSE)
text(x = boxplot.stats(product)$stats, labels = boxplot.stats(product)$stats, y = 1.25)
```

[BoxplotFiveNum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN2Ts.png)

As you can see in the picture, the values do not match.

In this case you can use quantile function:

```
text(x=quantile(produto),labels=quantile(produto),y=1.25)
```

[BoxplotQuantile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RJJZ.png)

Now you should get the same values as listed on summary function. Otherwise just ignore summary function and use fiveNum values instead. The differences occurs due to lack of universal agreement among statisticians.

A google search will show you the differences on quantiles calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
boxplot(X, axes = FALSE, staplewex = 1)
text(y = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, labels = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, x = 1.25)
```

How to do this but in multiple Boxplot

**Example data:**

```
a <- data.frame(
    Rank = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,1,3 ),
    Time = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), 
    Value = c(5,10,15,20,30,50,70,80,100,5,7,9,11,15,17,19,17,19,100,200,300,400,500,700,1000,200))

boxplot(a$Value[a$Rank==1] ~ a$Time[a$Rank==1])
```