# How to display only median value in boxplot?

Tags: r, label, boxplot, median

I need to create a boxplot which displays the median value in it. Not on the axes but directly inside the plot.

I found this thread very useful: [How to put values..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945434/how-to-put-values-of-on-box-plot-for-median-ist-quartlie-and-last-quartlle) with the solution:

```
boxplot(X, horizontal = TRUE, axes = FALSE, staplewex = 1)
text(x = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, labels = boxplot.stats(X)$stats, y = 1.25)
```

However, it displays all values and I could not figure out a way to customize it.

Comment: What do you mean? A text with the value of the median? Because a boxplot already shows the median.

Comment: Yeah, sure it shows the median, but i want the exact value of it, like a label! Thanks

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

`boxplot.stats(X)$stats[3]` shows only the median

```
boxplot(X, horizontal = TRUE, axes = FALSE, staplewex = 1)
text(x = boxplot.stats(X)$stats[3], labels = boxplot.stats(X)$stats[3], y = 1.25)
```

Will only have the `median` as the label